# i have some records in with different total. i want to sum it and display it in single row

Tags: vb.net

eg. i have records like this in my table.

```
  Name     Date        Salary
  Raja     01/10/2000   5000
  Raja     02/10/2000   5000
  Raja     03/10/2000   5000
  Anu      01/10/2000   3000
  Anu      02/10/2000   3000
  Anu      03/10/2000   3000
  King     01/10/2000   4000
  King     02/10/2000   4000
  King     03/10/2000   4000
```

i want to take print like the below eg using crystal report. (sum all the salary and display in single row).

Salary from 01/10/1981 To 03/10/1981

```
  NAME      Salary
  Raja      15,000
  Anu        9,000
  King      12,000
```

Comment: What's the question, exactly? At what point are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

use a simple sql statement, with group-by clause and sum on the salary column.

```
select Name, Sum(salary) 
from table
group by Name
```